# ggplot2 extension and add-on packages

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I've used [ggmap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/ggmap.pdf) for a while and I've recently become aware of [ggExtra](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggExtra/index.html) and [cowplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html). Could anyone point me in the direction of a comprehensive list of [ggplot2](http://cran.r-project.org/package=ggplot2) add-on packages?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html and the list of packages which depend on it as a starting point (particularly those w/ gg in the name).  I've reproduced some of this from that link below.

> **Reverse depends:**  alphahull, AmpliconDuo, aoristic, apsimr, arqas,
> bcrm, bde, benchmark, biomod2, bootnet, brms, caret, catenary,
> chemosensors, CINOEDV, cjoint, ClimClass, climwin, clustrd, coefplot,
> conformal, COPASutils, cowplot, Crossover, dae, Deducer, DepthProc,
> dfexplore, diffeR, dMod, dslice, DynNom, earlywarnings, eeptools,
> ESGtoolkit, fbroc, fishmove, freqparcoord, gapmap, gettingtothebottom,
> ggmap, ggmcmc, ggparallel, ggROC, ggswissmaps, ggtern, ggthemes,
> GOplot, gpmap, granovaGG, gsDesign, GSE, Hmisc, hyperSpec, idm,
> intsvy, learnstats, likeLTD, likert, localgauss, lsbclust, MCMC.OTU,
> MCMC.qpcr, mcprofile, MergeGUI, meteogRam, MissingDataGUI, mlr, mlxR,
> mosaic, MRMR, multilevelPSA, NeatMap, nullabor, orgR, OutbreakTools,
> PairedData, PASWR2, pauwels2014, PAWL, pbdPROF, pcrcoal, PedCNV,
> pequod, perry, perspectev, PhaseType, phylosim, pipe.design, pitchRx,
> PKgraph, PKreport, pointRes, PopED, popgraph, PPtreeViz, precintcon,
> prevR, PRISMA, profileR, ProgGUIinR, PSAboot, QCAtools, quadrupen,
> QualInt, quickpsy, radiant, RAM, Rcell, RcmdrPlugin.KMggplot2,
> rfPermute, RGraphics, RIGHT, RJafroc, rms, robustHD, rorutadis,
> rotations, rplos, RSA, RSDA, Rz, SciencesPo, season, sglr, slackr,
> SmarterPoland, SMFI5, snht, soc.ca, sotkanet, sparkTable, spcosa,
> spikeSlabGAM, spocc, sprm, statebins, SWMPr, synthpop, tcR, tdr,
> timeline, TriMatch, TripleR, tspmeta, useful, userfriendlyscience,
> vdg, waffle, xkcd, YourCast, zooaRch
>
> **Reverse imports:**  adegenet, alm,
> antitrust, asremlPlus, asVPC, BACA, BBEST, bdscale, bdvis, bear,
> Biograph, BioStatR, blowtorch, bmmix, breakpoint, broman, BTSPAS,
> capm, caretEnsemble, Causata, choroplethr, choroplethrAdmin1,
> classify, classyfire, clhs, clifro, complmrob, confidence, cooccur,
> cosinor, CosmoPhotoz, cplm, cutoffR, dcmr, DescribeDisplay, DFIT,
> diveRsity, dsm, DTR, DVHmetrics, dynsim, dynsurv, EasyHTMLReport,
> EcoGenetics, EffectLiteR, ega, egcm, emil, EpiDynamics, erer, evolqg,
> extracat, ez, ezsim, FAOSTAT, fheatmap, FinCal, fSRM, G2Sd,
> gfcanalysis, GGally, ggdendro, ggenealogy, ggExtra, ggRandomForests,
> ggsubplot, gitter, GraphPCA, greport, growcurves, growfunctions,
> hierarchicalDS, HighDimOut, HistDAWass, HLMdiag, IAT, kdetrees, kobe,
> llama, lmerTest, lmms, LocFDRPois, mapDK, marked, marmap, MAVIS,
> metagen, metaMix, Methplot, microbenchmark, micromap, mizer, Mobilize,
> multiDimBio, MultiMeta, ncappc, netgen, networkreporting,
> NeuralNetTools, ngramr, NMF, NORRRM, oaxaca, OpasnetUtils, optiRum,
> orderedLasso, P2C2M, pa, paleofire, partialAR, performanceEstimation,
> plot2groups, plotROC, pogit, PopGenReport, poppr, predictmeans,
> PReMiuM, pRF, primerTree, proteomics, qdap, qgraph, qwraps2,
> rags2ridges, rAltmetric, randomUniformForest, rbison, RDS, repra,
> reproducer, rfigshare, rfisheries, RFmarkerDetector, rgauges, rgbif,
> rinat, rnoaa, RobustEM, robustlmm, rSPACE, rvertnet, rWBclimate,
> saeSim, SCGLR, sdmvspecies, SeqFeatR, sidier, simPH, SixSigma, sjPlot,
> smoof, solarius, sorvi, statar, stcm, structSSI, strvalidator,
> survMisc, TcGSA, tigerstats, TreatmentSelection, treeclim, treemap,
> tvm, USAboundaries, vdmR, vmsbase, Wats, wppExplorer, wq, x.ent

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've added the reverse depends/reverse imports lists from the CRAN page.  It's a bit long but at least that should remain of some relevance even if the link becomes invalid.